# Why using naked return and the normal return give me different results?

Tags: go, rot13

I'm playing around with Golang tour and I wonder why using naked return give me the correct result but the normal one doesn't. This is the exercise that I have this problem https://tour.golang.org/methods/12.

The objective is to create a reader that can decipher rot13. and the rot13 function is already tested.

```
func (r rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err =  r.r.Read(b)
    for i, v := range b {
        b[i] = rot13(v)
    }
    return
}
```

The code above give me the correct result.

```
func (r rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    for i, v := range b {
    b[i] = rot13(v)
    }
    return r.r.Read(b)
}
```

And this doesn't change anything from the input stream.

Could anybody explain why? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a problem with returns, but in the first case you're reading the data in before transforming it and in the second case you're transforming junk in a buffer and only then reading in the data (and simply passing what has been read from the underlying reader).

While this is not required for correctness, I'd suggest you don't transform the whole buffer every time, but only the portion that has been read, i.e. changing your first example from `for i, v := range b` to `for i, v := range b[:n]`. That's because `io.Read` call is not able to modify length of slice `b`, but just its content.

Take a look at the documentation of [`io.Reader`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader), it should give you some more idea on how this interface is expected to work.

Comment: It's totally fine to use the whole buffer if they want to. It may be less efficient, but the specification of io.Reader allows for it: "*Even if Read returns n < len(p), it may use all of p as scratch space during the call.*"

Comment: @ReyCharles sure, that's why I only _suggested_ it (will make it more clear in the edit). I suspected that maybe the OP didn't necessarily understand how `io.Read` interface works, believing `b` is somehow shrunken by the call.

Comment: I've already read the documentation but still don't get it. And I have two questions from your answer.
1. You said "simply passing what has been read from the underlying reader". What do you mean by that. Could you give me some more explanation.
2. Since `b` is passed by value if I get it right, why can we modify it and have an affect to the variable that is passed in to the reader.

Comment: iboss: you get a slice to your rot13Reader.Read (by reference, slices are just pointers). This slice has some lenght and `r.r.Read` fills `b` with up to `len(b)` bytes. Once you have data in your `b` slice you want to transform it (rot13) and then return to the user how many bytes has been read to buffer `b`. Everything on the _original slice_ as (once again) slices are not passed by value (in a sense they're not being copied). Your second example reads the data from the underlying reader _after_ you perform rot13 transformation, that's why you don't see the data deciphered.

Comment: @tomasz: Slices _are_ passed by value, they _are_ being copied. Which is unrelated to the underlying array (which is not copied).

Comment: Volker you're 100% correct, again, I should be much more precise at my explanation. @iboss per Volker response, slices are passed by value, but they share the same underlying array (think: pointer to the array is being copied and they point to the same underlying array, hence you'll see modifications).

Comment: And this is leading to the situation when you can have two slices pointing to the same array, but having different (separate) lengths. That's why Read method is able to modify the array (visible to the caller) but cannot change the length in the same manner. Volker's comment is very important here, mine was misleading.

Answer (score 3):

The `Read()` operation mutates the input array `b`. In the second example the `rot13()` operations are overwritten by the `Read()` operation. Furthermore, the `rot13()` operation is performed before any data has been read into the array, so you're probably doing `rot13()` on garbage data.

If you wanted the second example to work you'd need to write something like this:

```
func (r rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := r.r.Read(b)
    for i, v := range b {
    b[i] = rot13(v)
    }
    return n, err 
}
```